# List Button not showing at top of List View for Custom Object in Lightning

Tags: lightning, administration, search-layout

I created "Log a Bug" List Button
[image]

After adding it to the Search Layout for Site Assessment object, I expect it to show here, but it does not.
[image]

Here's what the Search Layout looks like. All the other profiles inherit the default.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that to add a button to a list view, navigate to "Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic" (right below Search Layouts) and add the button to the List View Layout there.

Note that the button will not appear in the "Recently Viewed" list view, but it will appear in all the other list views.

Answer (score 1):

What solved this for me is editing the details of your object to Allow Search. List View Button Layout showed up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Setup > Object Manager > Case > In the sidebar > ListView Page Layout > Edit List View  then in the custom button section add your list button, And Save it.

You see the list button on the list views other than recently view.